# Storing date time in culture neutral format + C#

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime, datepicker

I accept date info from the user, via date picker. I need to store them in a culture neutral way. The problem I am facing is, if I store the date as per en-US format (based on calendar settings), namely 11/20/1990 it will fail to parse when the culture is en-GB.

And vice versa happens when culture is en-US, date stored as per UK format, dd/mm/yyyy refuses to parse. How do I store date info in a culture neutral way in a file so that, I get the date to work in both locations?

```
DateTime.TryParse(userEnteredValue, out result);
result.ToShortDateString(); //this is what I am doing
```

tried this code for invariant culture

```
string input = "20/10/1983";
DateTime userInput;

bool result = DateTime.TryParse(input, out userInput);

string invariantCulture = userInput.Date.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

DateTime storedValue;

result = DateTime.TryParse(invariantCulture, out storedValue);
```

tried this code with en-GB calendar settings, second statement DateTime.TryParse fails infact.

Comment: There is no such a culture called `en-UK`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to figure out a solution via this approach, please let me know if its correct.

The code which I use is below.

For Saving date time I use ticks as below.

```
DateTime userInput;

bool result = DateTime.TryParse(this.dpSave.Text, out userInput);

if (result)
{
   long ticks = userInput.Ticks;

   System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\folder\Ticks.txt", ticks.ToString());
 }
 else
 {
   MessageBox.Show("Date time parse failed");
 }
```

For loading it back, I use

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"D:\folder\Ticks.txt"))
{
   string contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Sandeep\Ticks.txt");

   long ticks;

   if (long.TryParse(contents, out ticks))
   {
     DateTime storedDateTime = new DateTime(ticks);
     MessageBox.Show("Stored Date" + storedDateTime.ToShortDateString());
   }
   else
   {
     MessageBox.Show("Unable to obtain stored dates");
   }
}
```

this seems to work, provided, I save using en-US culture and load using en-GB culture.

please let me know if this is the right approach!

Comment: I really did not see any comments nor updates after posting my suggestion for my approach. hence accepting this as answer.

Answer (score 5):

@Soner Gönül's answer is spot on if you are saving the dates to a database. However, you mention that you are looking to round-trip a `DateTime` to and from a *file*.

As the file is presumably a text file you'll need to write the `DateTime` in a culture neutral manner. You can do this by using the ["O" format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Roundtrip) specified on the `DateTime.ToString` method. This will output a string representation that complies with ISO 8601. The resultant string can be parsed using `DateTime.Parse` without the need for culture information.

As an example:

```
string filename = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
string usDateString = "11/18/2014 12:32"; // MM/dd/yyyy
string ukDateString = "18/11/2014 12:33"; // dd/MM/yyyy

//I'm mimicking you getting the DateTime from the user here    
//I'm assuming when you receive the date(s) from the front
//end you'll know the culture - if not then all bets are off. 
DateTime usDate = 
      DateTime.Parse(usDateString, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
DateTime ukDate = 
      DateTime.Parse(ukDateString, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"));

//write the dates to a file using the "o" specifier
File.AppendAllText(filename, usDate.ToString("o") + Environment.NewLine);
File.AppendAllText(filename, ukDate.ToString("o") + Environment.NewLine);

//read them back in as strings
string[] contents = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
        
foreach (var date in contents)
{
    //prove we can parse them as dates.
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(date).ToString());
}
```

This creates a file with the contents:

> 2014-11-18T12:32:00.0000000
>
> 2014-11-18T12:33:00.0000000

and on my system (in the UK) it prints:

> 18/11/2014 12:32:00
>
> 18/11/2014 12:33:00

Comment: I do not know the culture info, because, I do not know where the installation is, it might be US/UK region. The problem is US user may enter date in UK format or vice versa or once date is stored in UK format, the UK user may change calendar settings to point to en-US

Comment: @Sandepku - There are 2 separate issues here as far as I can tell. The first is when you receive a date from a user you need to parse it into a `DateTime` - for this you _have_ to know the Culture. The second issue is you want to persist the date in a file. For this you can use my code above and it will round trip safely _regardless of the users culture_.

Comment: @Sandepku - so do you always know the culture for the original user input? If so then the above will work for persisting the dates in a text file.

Comment: no I do not know, I just go by the current culture hoping it parses.

Comment: I have added an approach, could you let me know if this holds good or is there a flaw?

Answer (score 3):

> if I store the date as per en-US format...

**Please stop!** Looks like you try to save your `DateTime` values with their string representations.

A [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) doesn't have *any* implicit format. It has just date and time values. String representations of them can have a format. Generate your insert queries and pass your `DateTime` values *directly* with [parameterized way](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/).

Please read;

- [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

If you want to get string representations of your `DateTime` values with specific format, you can always use [`DateTime.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.DateTime.ToString.aspx) method and it's overloads.

Your `en-GB` culture can parse `MM.dd.yyyy` (since you use [`/` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#dateSeparator) which replaces itself supplied culture [`DateSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator(v=vs.110).aspx)) and `en-US` culture can parse `MM/dd/yyyy` as well.

But since you use `.ToShortDateString()` method, this represents your datetime based your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx) settings. As a solution, you can set this property which culture you want and `ToShortDateString` works based on it.

---

> ```
> result = DateTime.TryParse(invariantCulture, out storedValue);
> ```
>
> tried this code with en-UK calendar settings, second statement
> DateTime.TryParse fails infact.

Because this `DateTime.TryParse` uses your `CurrentCulture` and since your `invariantCulture` variable is  `10/20/1983 00:00:00`, that means this is not a standard date and time format for your `CurrentCulture`.

There is no such a culture as `en-UK` by the way.

---

`10/20/1983 00:00:00` is `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` format. But `en-GB` culture doesn't have this format as a standard date and time format, that's why your method returns `false`.

As an alternative, you can use custom format strings like;

```
string s = "10/20/1983 00:00:00";
string format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s, format, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"),
                           DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
}
```

Comment: well, I am just saving my string representation after doing DateTime.TryParse

Comment: DateTime.TryParse(userEnteredValue, out result); result.ToShortDateString(); this is what I am doing

Comment: @Sandepku What are the values of your `userEnteredValue` and `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: user entered value can be 20/10/1983 & CurrentCulture - en-GB OR 10/20/1983 & CurrentCulture - en-US

Comment: @Sandepku Updated. Take a look.

Comment: The date may be saved in en-GB format, later user may change calendar settings to en-US format. I cannot explicitly specify which culture. I am trying to write code independent of culture. please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: while fetching the value too, I try to do DateTime.TryParse, I do not use any culture info, I am expecting parsing to happen on the culture info. So I wish to store it in a format independent of culture.

Comment: @Sandepku If you want to use independent culture, you can use `InvariantCulture` for all your `IFormatProvider` in your `DateTime` methods. But I really want to point, a `DateTime` doesn't have _any_ format. String representations of them can have formats. There is no such a thing called: _A DateTime with en-GB format_

Comment: Tried this code string input = "20/10/1983";
            DateTime userInput;

            bool result = DateTime.TryParse(input, out userInput);

            string invariantCulture = userInput.Date.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            DateTime storedValue;

            result = DateTime.TryParse(invariantCulture, out storedValue);

Comment: @Sandepku Updated my answer again. Take a look.

Comment: I dont know how to put it, I currently have two installations over US/UK, running with same code base, I may end up with US date format in UK region and vice versa (since user may change calendar settings after he stores a date). And if i end up with installation in a third region, I still will need to cross check on the format, so kinda tentative!

Answer (score 2):

I bumped into this question and figured I'd bring in some other way nobody has mentioned yet:

[DateTime.ToBinary()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tobinary(v=vs.110).aspx) for serializing and [DateTime.FromBinary(Int64)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.frombinary(v=vs.110).aspx) for deserialization.

What these do is the following:
ToBinary() returns a long which can be easily stored in a culture invariant way.
FromBinary(Int64) will return a DateTime object from the long parameter supplied.
(They even take the date time Kind property into consideration).

And here's some code to go with it:

```
DateTime d1l = DateTime.Now;
long dl = d1l.ToBinary();
DateTime d2l = DateTime.FromBinary(dl);

DateTime d1u = DateTime.UtcNow;
long du = d1u.ToBinary();
DateTime d2u = DateTime.FromBinary(du);

Console.WriteLine("Local test passed: " + (d1l == d2l).ToString());
Console.WriteLine("d2l kind: " + d2l.Kind.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Utc test passed: " + (d1u == d2u).ToString());
Console.WriteLine("d2u kind: " + d2u.Kind.ToString());
```

And the console output:

```
Local test passed: True
d2l kind: Local
Utc test passed: True
d2u kind: Utc
```

I find this to be pretty neat!

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "24. 11. 2001";
d = DateTime.Parse(s, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("sk-SK"));
```

1. en-AU (English Austrailia): 24/11/2001
2. en-IA (English India): 24-11-2001
3. en-ZA (English South Africa): 2001/11/24
4. en-US (English United States): 11/24/2001

i suspect you prefer English (India) (en-IA).

But if you really can't decide what culture to use when converting dates to strings and vice-versa, and the dates are never meant to be shown to a user, then you can use the Invariant Culture:

```
String s = "11/24/2001" //invariant culture formatted date

d = DateTime.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //parse invariant culture date

s = d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //convert to invariant culture string
```

Comment: what If I modify the input date to 24/11/2001 in the sample code? I doubt it parses.

Comment: Check for [Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/5hh873ya(v=vs.90).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score 0):

a) Exchange data shall always be stored culture invariant (xml etc)

b)You've gotta to be careful with the terminology.
What you exactly mean is culture INVARIANT (and not 'culture neutral').
There are three types of cultures:
1) invariant
2) culture neutral (e.g. "en")
3) culture specific (e.g "en-US")

Answer (score 0):

```
public DateTime getdate3()
{

    CultureInfo Invc = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;    //culture
    string cul = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;

    CultureInfo us = new CultureInfo(cul);
    string shortUsDateFormatString = us.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;//pattern


    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now);

    TimeZoneInfo myZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"); //india zone
    DateTime dateindia = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dt, myZone);

    string dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dateindia).ToString(shortUsDateFormatString); //string format
```

}

Comment: It would improve understanding if you can add explanation to your answer